# reset button is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, reset-button

I have an asp.net web page that displays data that was returned from the database. However, when I attempt to click "Reset" (`<input id="btnReset" type="reset" value="Clear" />)` the button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably looking for this

```
<asp:Button id="btnReset" Text="reset it!" runat="server" onclick="btnReset_onClick" />
```

so you can do stuff in your codebehind

Comment: I need something that will not trigger validation controls;

Answer (score 5):

The reset button will only erase the data the user entered after the page was rendered. So if you dont make any changes in the page, the reset button wont do anything.

Also, Reset is a client side operation. it wont post-back the page to the server.

Comment: Succinct explanation and the solution to my "Why isn't the reset button working" woes.